# PHP, how can I produce a string, a unique list of values up to three items, for use after IN in a query?

Tags: php

I need to produce a string for use in an query e.g.

```
SELECT whatever from Keywords.word IN (here);
```

At the moment I have string which could be

```
$search = "one word or four";
```

or

```
$search = "one";
```

or

```
$search = "one one";
```

I need to validate this into some acceptable for my query.
I want a unique list of words, separated with a comma up to a maximum of three.

This is what I have so far.

```
$array = explode(" ",$search);
$unique = array_unique ($array);
```

I'm sure there must be a quicker way than evaluating each of the items for blank and selecting the first three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some array functions, like this:

```
$arr   = explode(" ", $search);                   // explode into chunks
$uniq  = array_unique($arr);                      // make sure chunks are unique
$three = array_slice($uniq, 0, 3);                // take first three chunks
$in    = sprintf("'%s'", implode("','", $three)); // produces 'first','second','third'
```

Of course you can do that in one line:

```
$in = sprintf("'%s'", implode("','", array_slice(array_unique(explode(" ", $search)), 0, 3)));
```

Comment: im just curious - why do you choose to use sprintf rather than something like `$in = "'" . implode("','", $three) . "'";`   I've seen other coders do the same and i never understood the preference.

Comment: I find it rather easier to read. But that is just a personal preference, I guess.

Comment: Actually, I started off with PHP. Then went on to Java and C. But in fact I picked printf() in C, yes. And I liked it straight away.